# How can I add withCredentials to existing jquery.get statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written my application in javascript and jquery and have made extensive use of jquery.get, jquery.post and jquery.when.  This works fine testing on my localhost, but now I need to connect to an api on another server I find I have to add xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }, to all my http requests.  Is there any way I can include this in my jquery.get statement, or do I have to convert them all to jquery.ajax statements?

Comment: Have you had a look at the `$.ajaxSetup();` command - sets up the overall settings for every get / post etc request. Not sure if it covers withCredentials though.

Answer (score 18):

Try

```
$.ajaxSetup({xhrFields: { withCredentials: true } });
```

in your `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

Comment: Many Thanks, it seems to work.  I just couldn't find any examples using google.

Comment: pleased it works! feel free to accept the answer :-)

Comment: user3279063 you should accept CharlesA's answer. It worked for you and it worked for me :-)